# Featured image on page set as "Posts page" in Settings > Reading

Tags: images

Settings > Reading is set to "Actualites", which is a static page I created that uses index.php as template. In it, the_post_thumbnail() doesn't work (although I set a featured image in my "Actualites" page. Why?

So I tried this:

```
function wp_get_ID_by_page_name($page_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $page_name_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '".$page_name."'");
    return $page_name_id;
}
$blog_id = wp_get_ID_by_page_name( 'actualites' );
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $blog_id, 'page_thumbnail' );
```

Not only it doesn't work, it makes the images of my posts not show up. Again, why?

Contents of index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class='page_container'>

    <div class='page_container_content'>

        <div class='page_thumbnail page_thumbnail_green_border'>
            <?php 
            $blog_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $blog_id, 'page_thumbnail' ); 
            ?>
        </div>  

        <div id='petites_annonces_wrap' class='page_container_content_text'>                

            <div id='actus'>

                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                ?>
                    <div class='item'>

                        <?php 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                        ?>
                            <div class='page_annonce_thumb'>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'activite_mosquee' ); ?>
                            </div>                              
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <div class='page_annonce_content'>
                            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                <?php
                endwhile;
                endif; 
                ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class='page_container_sidebar'>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `index.php` template is used? Static front pages use either `front-page.php` or `page.php` by default.

Comment: It's the posts page not front page.

Comment: No wonder it's not working. Use `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )` to get the page ID, no need for your custom SQL function.

Comment: Same result: neither the posts page's featured image nor the featured image of the posts displayed by the loop below work, the image "alt" text appears instead. The mere execution of $blog_id = wp_get_ID_by_page_name( 'actualites' ); or $blog_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); makes all images of the page fail. One of the weirdest bugs I've ever seen.

Comment: Post the contents of your `index.php`

Comment: Ok, I edited the question.

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump( $blog_id )`? I know in MultiSite `$blog_id` is a global, not sure if it affects single installs - either way, might be a good idea to use a safer variable name.